# How do i resolve this error?undefined method `at_css' for #<Mechanize::Page:0xb4b76434>

Tags: ruby, mechanize

NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `at_css' for #
At the time of run this code,
result.at_css("body").text

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: use `page.at` and `page.search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `root` method on the `Mechanize::Page` object first:

```
page = Mechanize.new.get("http://....")
page.root.at_css('...')
```

`root` will return a [Nokogiri::HTML::Document](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/HTML/Document), which implements the `at_css` method.

Comment: result.search("body").text     # this also working,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

page.root.search('...')
Its Working